# robocopy cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, robocopy

I wrote a small BATCH-File to sync my PC and Notebook folders for university.

```
REM set tdate=%date: =%
REM set tdate=%tdate:/=%
REM
REM set ttime=%time: =%
REM set ttime=%ttime:.=%
REM set ttime=%ttime: =%

@echo off
cls
set Date format = %date%
set dd = %date:~0,2%
set mm = %date:~3,2%
set yyyy = %date:~6,4%

set Time format = %time%
set hh = %time:~0,2%
set mm = %time:~3,2%
set ss = %time:~6,2%

set Timestamp=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
REM ROBOCOPY D:\Music F:\Music /MIR > "C:\Robocopy\%Timestamp%.log" /MT:8 /R:1 /TEE
robocopy D:\Documents\Studium \\NOTEBOOK\Documents\Studium /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5 > "C:\Robocopy\%Timestamp%.log"
```

Everything works fine on when running this on my PC. When doing the same script on my NOTEBOOK, just changing the Paths

```
robocopy C:\Users\Myuser\Documents\Studium \\PC\Documents\Studium /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5 > "C:\Robocopy\%Timestamp%.log"
```

I get `robocopy cannot find the path specified`. When I remove `> "C:\Robocopy\%Timestamp%.log"` the script works fine. The Folder C\obocopy does exst, I run the BATCH-Script from this directory...running as administrator doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the date/time configuration the same on both machines?

Comment: Yes, date and time is the same and on both machines and C:\Robocopy directory exists. I run the scripts while being in the C:\Robocopy directory.

Comment: Is `\\PC` your real path or did you fill it in instead of say `\\192.168.0.10`? Anyway, if `\\PC` should point to your PC, check that this is its NetBIOS name and that `\\PC\Documents\` is shared via the network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the quote?
Have you tried creating the file before logging?
Have you tried to save it somewhere else?
Have you tried to use `>>` instead of `>`?

For sure one of these will fix it.